# How can I assign a value of a existing key in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I have to check if a key is in the dictionary or not. if it is there I have to assign at the variable the value of the key otherwise create a new key with a value for a raw_input. I write the code below but it doesn't work. I have to check if the key is in the dictionary or not.

For example I have a database of food recipe. "Oil" is almost in all recipes so i can't insert a raw_input for all a row of database. So I want to create a dictionary and select the value there.

For example in the database i have 100 row with ingredient "oil". I  match this database with another. The key is the name of ingredient (in this case "oil") and the value is the characteristic (corn oil). Each row with the key "oil" must have the value "corn oil". Can i make this using a dictionary?

```
dict={}
for item in list:
#if the item is not in the list, I assign new value for a raw_input
    if dict.get(item) is None:
        dict[item]=value
    #if the item is in the list, I assing the previous value
    else:
        dict[item]=value
```

Can you help me, please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Currently your code just inserts `value` into the dict regardless of whether the key exists or not. What is your issue? What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening? Please, clarify.

Comment: You're doing the same thing in the if and the else, what do you expect to happen ?

Comment: I have to check if the key is in the dictionary or not. If the key is in the dictionary i have to assing the same value at the new variable otherwise i have to key a couple {key: value}. For example i have a database of food recipe. Salt is almost in all so i can't insert a raw_input for all a row of database. I want to create a dictionary and select the value there.

Comment: Use `if item not in dict:`.

Comment: You talk about `raw_input` but i can't see `raw_input` in your code....you're basically repeating the same thing whether the item is there or not

Comment: Indeed, both `if` branches do same thing. To check if key `item` is present in `dict_` write `if item in dict_:`. Also, don't redefine built-in names: `dict` is type name.

Comment: It would be great if you can give the example with the sample list and the dict that you want as final result. Because what you are asking is unclear to me

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you always do dict[item] = value for any case, both if exists the item at the dictionary or not, then you have to create a new variable, for the dictionary, but I don't know that method you want to use, or what it will be the new key if the key already exists.

Sorry for my poor english if you don't understand something, write it!

Answer (score 1):

Item assignment will in both cases replace any existing value with the new one; there is no need to check if the key already exists.

```
d[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help. You assign a new value if key is not present, else don't since the key already exist

```
dict_a={}
for item in list:
    if item not in dict_a:
        dict[item]= raw_input() #Assign your raw_input value here

#If the value exist, you don't have to do any change
```

Comment: If the key exists, i have to assing the value to the new variable. For example in the database i have 100 row with ingredient "oil". I  match this database with another. The key is the name of ingredient (in this case "oil") and the value is the characteristic (corn oil). Each row with the key "oil" must have the value "corn oil". Can i make this using a dictionary?

Comment: This is what I understood. Correct me if I am wrong.
You have two tables where one table has ingredients in each single row and the other has columns such as | oil | corn oil | , if you find palm oil in the ingredients, you want to store it as  | oil | palm oil| in that table, right?

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
d = {}

if item in d:
    d[item] = prev_value
else:
    d[item] = new_value

# OR in one line
d[item] = prev_value if item in d else new_value
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it:

```
dict={}
for item in list:

    if item not in dict.keys():
        dict[item] = None

    dict[item]=value
```

If item is not present in dictionary's keys, just create one with `None` as starting value. Then, assign value to key (now You're sure it is there).

Answer (score 0):

execute this it will return what you want..

```
dict={}
item = 'key'
if item in dict.keys(): # item will be some key 
 dict[item]=value
else:
 get_key = raw_input('new key name you want:')
 dict[get_key] = raw_input('value for corresponding key:')

print 'di',dict
```

output for this :

```
new key name you want:my_key
value for corresponding key:
di {'my_key': 'val_for_it'}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if item in dict else input()

```
dict = {}
for item in selection_list:
    dict[item] = new_val if item in dict else raw_input()
```